# custom search engine refused to display in a iframe in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin''

Tags: iframe, google-custom-search, google-search-api

Hi I am trying to put the link of cse results in an iframe to display it in my website but when I do it gives me this error refused to display in a iframe  in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin''
I copied other websites cse results link and it worked fine so it is not a problem from my server but from the link is there a way to permit putting cse results in an iframe ?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Using and iframe is no longer a supported configuration:
https://support.google.com/customsearch/answer/2631042

Use the Custom Search Element instead:
https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/tutorial/implementingsearchbox

Comment: How come other website are using iframe to show cse results ?

Comment: It's a legacy configuration.  It still seems to work for CSEs that have it.
If you're doing something new, then Search Element is the way to go.

Comment: why popular queries do not show as google search result they get displayed in my website as a link ?